# Why is continue behaving like a break in this while statement?

Tags: python, while-loop

When I run the code below, continue behaves like break because it stops any more outcome. Also, when I run it again the output disappears -- and on the left it says In [*], does anyone know why is this happening? I keep having to go back and restart the kernel

```
while x < 5:
    if x == 2:
        continue
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Comment: because x is never incremented after it reaches 2

Comment: It **does not** behave like break. On the contrary, nothing is interrupted, you endup with an infinite loop, but without output.

Comment: In that case, what can I do to print all the numbers that are less than 5 except 2?

Comment: `if x != 2: print(x)`…

Comment: Replace the `continue` with `break` and see for youself it they behave the same.

Comment: That's what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get printed all except 2, you better rewrite you snippet.
Something like that:

```
while x < 5:
    x += 1
    if x == 2:
        continue
    print(x)
```

Cause you really didn't let `x` increment in your first edition, when it achieved 2.

Comment: Except that with this the first value isn't being output, since you increment before you print.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, because in that case you just started with x-1 value. For example with x = -1, you will printing from 0.